# HTML/Javascript/CSS Boxes stacking on each other?

Tags: javascript, html

So I got "boxes" which show picture. Pictures are got from Javascript foreach loop and it enters them with html. The problem is boxes are stacking on each other, how could I prevent that. Like they have "space" between of each box?

Javascript:

```
$("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col s2' style='padding:0%;'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light hoverable' style='margin:0;' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='card-content center-align' style='padding:6%'>" + item.name + "<img title=\"" + item.name + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/'style='width:15vw;height:auto;'>" + numberWithCommas(item.price) + " Coins</div></div></li>");
```

Comment: They're currently touching and you want padding in between?

Comment: A screenshot of what's actually happening would also be helpful

Comment: http://prntscr.com/arel54

Comment: It is pretty weird to use the <li> tag for this (as the other commenter had mentioned). Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Try adding padding to right of in between elements, lets check whether it fix...as no idea here without knowing the actual css..

Comment: We can help you better if you set up a jsfiddle

Comment: You need a space between this url and the word style: `item.iconurl + "/' style`

Comment: I have no idea why I used <li> for that :D. @Dreamweaver what you mean by that?

Comment: Okay, I added it. Didn't changed anything.

Comment: It is happening because I've used `width:15vw;` I don't know is there anything "better" to use except that? That made "perfect" things for me/=.

Comment: Figure out how many pixels wide it should be (e.g. 50) and use 50px instead of 15vw

Comment: Still, if your viewport is the box in the background, surrounding all of the keys, 15% of that width should be plenty.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` is used for creating lists, like you would use bullets in MS Word. Try using  instead and changing `style='padding:0;'` to `style='padding: 15px` (or however many px or % you want in between). Secondly, you really could be using float.

```
<div class='col s2' style='padding:5%;float:left;'>
   <div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light hoverable' style='margin:0;' id='itemID'>
      <div class='card-content center-align' style='padding:6%'>
         Item Name
         <img title="Item Name" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/iconURL/' style='width:15vw;height:auto;'>
         price Coins
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You should start by getting the html and CSS right, before you try doing it dynamically with javascript. Especially since we have no idea what css has been set for your classes (col, s2, card, item-card, etc)

Comment: If you don't get figured out shortly, go here https://jsfiddle.net/sab6po7c/ and enter your html, css, and javascript so we can help.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work out, the boxes just went "more center"

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the others saying `<li>` is only for lists. `<li>` is used to semantically group relevant data together, which is exactly what you are doing. Without seeing your css, it's tough to really troubleshoot, but this should totally work as long as your `<li>`s are using display: inline-block, or just regular blocks (which is the default for li) with float: left.

That said, it seems like you are doing something wacky with the width of either the `img` or the `<li>`. Your images are all the same width, so just give them a static pixel width.

**edit:**

Try something like this...

```
$("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col s2' style='padding:0%;'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light hoverable' style='margin:0;' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='card-content center-align' style='padding:6%'>" + item.name + "<img title=\"" + item.name + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/'style='width:150px;height:auto;'>" + numberWithCommas(item.price) + " Coins</div></div></li>");
```

Comment: Alright so. How could I make "space(s)" between them, I could change vw to smaller. If I change "first" padding. Then it just "moves" it downwards and it gets kinda right, but it's basically like middle and it looks ugly.

Comment: VW is for view port size. So if you used width:15vw, it would be 15% of the view port. Your images are bigger than 15% of the view port, which is why they are overlapping. Just change them to something like width:150px, and adjust the px until they fit. Really though, it's tough to  tell without seeing your code...

Comment: I don't have much more code, other is just getting pictures.

Comment: Okay, did that. Example. 200px is enough for me, but again.. "boxes" are getting connected

Comment: Picture size = makes box size bigger

Comment: try this: $("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col s2' style='padding:15px;'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light hoverable' style='margin:0;' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='card-content center-align' style='padding:6%'>" + item.name + "<img title=\"" + item.name + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/'style='width:150px;height:auto;'>" + numberWithCommas(item.price) + " Coins</div></div></li>");

Comment: or: $("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col s2' style='padding:0px;'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light hoverable' style='margin:0;' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='card-content center-align' style='padding:6%'>" + item.name + "<img title=\"" + item.name + "\" draggable='false' src='steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/"; + item.iconurl + "/'style='width:150px;padding:15px;height:auto;'>" + numberWithCommas(item.price) + " Coins</div></div></li>");